# Spring: Check in code if url has security set to none

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-filters

It is possible to check in Spring `Interceptor` `preHandle()` method if requested URL is secured by Spring Security or not (has set `security="none"`) ?

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
     if(isSecured(request) && !paymentRegistered())
        response.sendRedirect("/payment")
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}
private boolean isSecured(HttpServletRequest request){
//how to check if url has security=none
}
```

My problem is that after successful login I want to check if user has payed for service. If not I want to redirect to payment page. My idea is to write custom request scope filter or interceptor and check if user has registered payment in database. Problem is that I do not want to filter non secured URLs such as resources, login page, error pages etc. Also payment page (which is secured) should be available.
Maybe better idea is to write custom security filter and add custom flag to `Principal` object such as `servicePayed` alongside with other security flags: `enabed`, `accountNonExipired` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it writing a custom [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html), mainly based in the simple implementation [SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html).

In your implementation, you should overwrite onAuthenticationSuccess method, and there check if you should redirect the user to the payment page or not.

```
/**
     * Calls the parent class {@code handle()} method to forward or redirect to the target
     * URL, and then calls {@code clearAuthenticationAttributes()} to remove any leftover
     * session data.
     */
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if(mustCompletePayment(authentication)){
            handle(request, response, authentication);
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        }
}
```

Then just write a kind of mustCompletePayment using the authentication object, from which you must be able to check if the user must complete payment or not, or if you already made a custom UserDetailsService to check it during authentication, just check that indicator in your authentication object

**EDIT:**
If what you really want to do is to avoid any action for the logged user while he does not complete the payment, I would manage with granted authorities.

As I see, the key here is to translate the fact that the user has yet not paid into the authorization layer in a way you could take advantage of it.

You already have implemented the logic to discover if a user has completed payment information or not, so you could write your own [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html), so in the

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)throws UsernameNotFoundException
```

you could check that and in case the user has not complete the payment, just erase any returning granthedAuthority from the UserDetails and let only one stating that the user must complete the payment, let's say ROLE_USER_HAS_NOT_PAID.

Then, in security http config (this is xml version but maybe you are using java config), make such a kind of mappings:

```
<security:http ...>
     ...
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/secured/payment/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_USER_HAS_NOT_PAID" />
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/secured/**" access="ROLE_USER_HAS_PAID" />
     ...
</security:http>
```

With this config, payment page would be accessible for any user, wherever the user has paid or not, while other pages are available only for users who had already paid. Only, be carefull as you must renew the user's granthed authorities once the user has paid to made him available every page.

This way, the AuthenticationSuccessHandler should not eval other than the user granthed authorities to decide where to redirect the user. I have made this several times by building a AuthenticationSuccessHandler based on a ordered map where I configured a landing page for each of the granthed authorities which need their own landing page.

Now any logged user action is forbidden if he has cont complete payment, so a HTTP 403 would be raised while trying to access any other secured resource. But you want don't want just to block the user from doing anything else, you want to redirect it to the payment page. Here you need an [AccessDeniedHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html), where you could do more or less the same check:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAccessDeniedHandler extends
        AccessDeniedHandlerImpl implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private String errorPage = "/error/403";

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
            AccessDeniedException arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if(context.getAuthentication() != null && context.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()){
            if(context.getAuthentication().getAuthorities().contains("ROLE_USER_HAS_NOT_PAID")){
                this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(arg0, arg1, "/secured/payment/pay");
                return;
            }
        }
        this.redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(arg0, arg1, this.getErrorPage());        
    }

    public RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }

    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    public void setErrorPage(String errorPage) {
        this.errorPage = errorPage;
    }

    public String getErrorPage() {
        return errorPage;
    }

}
```

This way you would redirect users which still must pay to your payment page and in any other case to a default 403 page

Comment: It was my first idea. Problem is that you use permission mechanism to evaluate your business logic. You have permissions and you remove it artificially because of business logic. But considering all other possible solutions it seems to be the best

Comment: Actually I don't see it like a problem. You are just taking a decission of where to redirect an arriving user depending on his profile. One usual case is to redirect to one landing page or another depending on the user's granthed authorities, I've had to make such a thing many times.

Comment: But what is your solution for typing URL in browser ? AuthenticationSuccessHandler fires only during login process. It will redirect to payment, but when user type another URL in browser it will work. My idea is to vanish principal object from all granted permissions except payment permission. Do you have any better idea ?

Comment: Please have a look at my edit. I would do just as you said in your last comment

Comment: Almost :) I remove all permissions but PAYMENT_PERMISSION (if user have) during creation Principal object. After login user is redirected to desirable page based on permissions. All other pages typed by hand in URL bar returns 403.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if there's a way to get such information from Spring Security. But maybe if you do not have a lot of urls which are not secured than you can do something like this:

```
private boolean isSecured(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();
    return !(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")
            && (requestUri.contains("error/")
            || requestUri.startsWith("resources/"))
    );
}
```

Or move those non-secured resources to some common start path and use the idea described in the code above.

Comment: There is more than two URL's. But It is not a problem. Problem with your solution is that you duplicate logic connected with secured URL's. You have to provite path in security settings and in filter. Maybe you can suggest better approach than filters ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find a way to do that, but IMHO you should not, because it is likely to require to dive in Spring Security internals.

If you want to only use Spring Security the way it was designed for, you could implement a custom `AccessDecisionVoter`. For example, if could only vote for one single security attributes starting with PAYMENT. You put that security attribute in spring security configuration:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/..." access="PAYMENT,ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

to restrict access to user having payed or having the ADMIN role

To declare a custom voter, you must replace the default access decision manager. First you declare it:

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
            <bean class="your.package.PaymentVoter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then you insert it in your `<http>` element:

```
<http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
```

Comment: Ok but what is your solution ? Add custom voter, evaluate that service is not payed and what's next ? Security will not authenticate user, but user have to be authenticated in order to pay for service.